# Как сохранить токен в sessionStorage при входе?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Есть две функции, отвечающие за авторизацию пользователя:

```
const onSignIn = async (passPhrase) => {
  await setAccountData(passPhrase);
  if (status.value === coreSvc.eStatus.Connected) {
    router.push('/wallet');
  }
};

const setAccountData = async (passPhrase) => {
  store.dispatch('account/logOut');
  store.dispatch('account/setAccountInfo', null);
  if (passPhrase !== '' && passPhrase !== null) {
    const result = coreSvc.getAccountByPassPhrase(passPhrase);
    await openStore({ database: process.env.Db, table: TablesName.ACCOUNTS });
    const exists = await getItem(result.address);
    console.log(result.address);
    if (exists === null) {
      await setItem(result.address, JSON.stringify(result));
    }
    await store.dispatch('account/setAccountInfo', result);
  }
  await coreSvc.checkNetworkStatus(store);
};
```

В функции `setAccountData()` есть `result.address` из которого нужно сделать токен хранящийся в `sessionStorage`

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **sessionStorage** существует только в рамках текущей вкладки браузера.
> При обновлении страницы/вкладки, данные в sessionStorage продолжат существовать. 
> Если вкладку закрыть и открыть заново, данные удаляться.

Добавьте в вашу функцию `setAccountData` сохранение значения в хранилище

```
sessionStorage.setItem('token', result.address);
```

`result.address` - должна быть строка.

В нужном месте кода, где вам необходимо получить данные, пишите

```
const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, я уже так сделал и все работает :)