# Как при перезагрузке страницы сохранять прогресс игры

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, localstorage, хранение-данных

Пишу тетрис, ситуация такая, игрок зарегался в игре и во время его сессии произошла перезагрузка страницы, нужно чтобы весь прогресс остался и игра продолжалась, помогите!
Тетрис на канвасе.
И еще, как хранить информацию, а именно имя и количество очков?

Comment: В идеальном варианте, нужна база данных. А так можете посмотреть на [sessionStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473260/1473295#1473295) или [localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/1452946#1452946). Более подробно о возможностях в [документации learn.javascript.ru/localstorage](https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage)

Comment: @SwaD а почему не webSql или indexedDb?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Как мне кажется, это уже избыточно, что бы хранить несколько параметров. А в случае, что есть система регистраций на сайте, то логичнее организовать хранение данных по игроку на сервере, а локально хранить минимальные данные.