# Как сделать в JS задать стили, которые будут сохраняться для каждой последующей страницы HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, domdocument

Вопрос следующий:
У меня есть задача создать версию для слабовидящих.
Столкнулся с проблемой - стили этой версии отменяются при переходе на другую страницу сайта.

Как прописать стили (работа с изображениями, шрифтами и тд), чтобы они сохранялись, как данные для HTML?

Прописывая на body получаю отрицательный результат, который указал в начале.

Не получается додумать, как правильно через JS обратиться к стилям, чтобы они переносились на остальные HTML.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если это не одностраничный сайт, то каждый переход на другую страницу вызывает перезагрузку страницы(с сервера) и сам js начинает на странице работать с чистого листа. В вашем случае, стоит посмотреть в сторону сохранения параметра стилей на строне клиента, допустим [localStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1452944/1452946#1452946) или [sessionStorage](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1473260/1473295#1473295). Думаю этого будет достаточно. [Вот еще варианты хранения данных на клинте](https://learn.javascript.ru/data-storage)

Comment: SwaD, спасибо большое за рекомендацию! Сейчас буду изучать.